# Print different values with different types depending on some condition with operator<<?

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to print the number args if they are > 1 or "none" if they are <= 1. The only way I know how to do this is:

```
cout << "number of args: ";
if (argc > 1)
  cout << argc - 1;
else
  cout << "none";
cout << endl;
```

But then I can't chain the `<<` operator. Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
cout << "number of args: "
     << argc > 1 ? argc - 1 : "none"
     << endl;
```

But this isn't possible because the types from a ternary if are different.

Ideas?

Comment: Can't think of one to do this directly, unless `to_string` `argc - 1` counts. You can write your own I/O manipulator, I suppose.

Comment: *But then I can't chain the `<<` operator*… so? Do you have a reason to avoid the `if` construct? If not, you will be better off by writing the simple if check and moving on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way. Handle with a string.

```
std::cout << "number of args: "
          << (argc > 1 ? std::to_string(argc - 1) : "none")
          << std::endl;
```

It has some superfluous cost to change the string. But it is easy to read and maintain if it is used once. And the reason the parentheses are required is that the shift operator(<<) has higher precedence than ternary conditional operator(?:) or relational operators (>).

Comment: You should explain why the parentheses are required.

Comment: I would avoid this construct. Granted that the original goal is misled (*chaining* per se is not an advantage), but this solution will incur additional costs (on memory allocation, regardless of the number of arguments) and potentially the cost of converting the integer to a string (if `argc > 1`)

Comment: The shift operator(`<<`) has higher precedence than ternary conditional operator(`?:`) or relational operators (`>`). So the parentheses are required.

Comment: I agree that this solution is rough.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - additional memory allocation, yes, but the integer will be converted to a string anyway if it's going to be printed.

Comment: It's not just the `argc - 1`-to-`string` conversion, `"none"`  may be converted to a `std::string` before printing too.  Still, this is for command line argument parsing - a one off - and performance can reasonably be expected to be irrelevant.  +1.

Comment: @Chan I *know* why the parentheses are required, I'm saying it should appear in your answer.

Comment: @remyabel I know you knew that. I just forgot I can edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own class to do the limit printing:

```
class limit {
    int lim;
    int k;
public:
    limit(int lim_, int k_) : lim(lim_), k(k_) {}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const limit& lim);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const limit& lim) {
    if (lim.k < lim.lim) {
        ostr << "none";
    } else {
        ostr << lim.k - lim.lim;
    }
    return ostr;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello " << limit(1, 15) << endl;
    cout << "World " << limit(1, -1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/zkjMsT)

The `limit` class holds two numbers - the limit (1 in the demo) and the number to be printed. It provides an operator `<<` for printing, which uses your conditional statement to print either the value over the limit, or `"none"`. This lets you write `cout << limit(1, argc)`, and produce the desired printout.

Answer (score 3):

If you place the `<<` within the ternary expressions, it unifies the types for both the true and false cases.

```
argc > 1 ? std::cout << argc - 1 : std::cout << "none";
```

You can use a helper template function to make things a bit more seamless:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream & argp (const T &x) {
    return std::cout << "number of args: " << x;
}

(argc > 1 ? argp(argc - 1) : argp("none")) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more general solution, you could create a (template) class that stores references to two objects and a bool. Then overload `operator<<` to choose which member to print based on the bool.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class be_careful_this_class_holds_references_to_its_constructor_arguments
{
public:
    be_careful_this_class_holds_references_to_its_constructor_arguments(
        bool b, T const& t, U const& u)
        :choose_first(b), first(t), second(u)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& os,
        be_careful_this_class_holds_references_to_its_constructor_arguments const& p)
    {
        if (p.choose_first)
        os << p.first;
        else
            os << p.second;
        return os;
    }
private:
    bool choose_first;
    T const& first;
    U const& second;
};
```

Using this class is a bit cumbersome though, you have to name the types. You can fix that with a helper function:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
be_careful_this_class_holds_references_to_its_constructor_arguments<T,U>
pick(bool choice, T const& first, U const& second)
{
    return be_careful_this_class_holds_references_to_its_constructor_arguments<T,U>(choice,first,second);
}
```

Then you can just call this function, passing a condition to the first parameter, and your two options of what to print to the second and third parameters:

```
std::cout << pick(argc > 1, argc - 1, "none") << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 This is perfectly safe for the illustrated usage, but it's noteworthy that the bound references to potential temporaries (e.g. `argc - 1`) will only be valid until the full statement calling `pick` completes execution.  In other words, `auto x = pick(b, ..., ...);` where either of the `...`s is a temporary doesn't create a usable `x`.

Comment: @TonyD: True. Hopefully the class name change will help prevent those kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of adding to the existing craziness....

Eventual usage supported:

```
xstream xs(std::cout) << If(argc <= 1) << argc - 1 << _else << "none" << _endif << '\n';
```

Note that this does ***not*** short-circuit evaluation of the "if" or "else" branches the way `?`, `:` and `;` does, but it doesn't require a conversion to a common type either....

Implementation (also at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/bw9L6i).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct If { If(bool active) : active_(active) { } bool active_; };
struct Else { } _else;
struct Endif { } _endif;

class xstream
{
  public:
    xstream(std::ostream& os) : os_(os) { }

    template <typename T>
    friend xstream& operator<<(xstream& s, const T& t)
    {
        if (s.active_) s.os_ << t;
        return s;
    }

  private:
    bool active_;
    std::ostream& os_;
};

template <>
xstream& operator<< <If>(xstream& s, const If& _if)
{
    s.active_ = _if.active_;
    return s;
}

template <>
xstream& operator<<<Else>(xstream& s, const Else& _else)
{
    s.active_ ^= true;
    return s;
}

template <>
xstream& operator<<<Endif>(xstream& s, const Endif& _endif)
{
    s.active_ = true;
    return s;
}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    xstream xs(std::cout);
    xs << If(argc <= 1) << argc - 1 << _else << "none" << _endif << '\n';
}
```

(Note that the `xstream` constructor only keeps a reference to the stream it's controlling, so the latter's lifetime must outlive the former's use under penalty of undefined behaviour).